# Watching logs with less +F freezes after a while

Tags: linux, logging, less, tail

`less +F` is a great command for watching logs, but it has very annoying issue. After a while it stops updating log file and requires restart. Is there any way to make it follow file forever?

Comment: Are they being rotated/recreated underneath?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `less --follow-name` reloads file after changes.

Comment: `less +F --follow-name`, this does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess "less" does not stop arbitrarily, but because less keeps reading the filedescriptor of the file opened at start.  But then the logfile is switched; it is renamed or deleted, and a new file with the same name is created receiving the log. However "less" just keeps reading the old file, and nothing is appended anymore.

What you want in that case is:

```
 tail -F file.log
```

you can use the scrollbuffer of the terminal emulator as a limited scrollback.